# Convert integer w/6 implied decimals to float, correcting rounding errors in Python

Tags: python

Under RHEL, Python v 2.6.6

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> n = 5352800
>>> d = 1000000
>>> n/d
5.3528000000000002
>>>
```

I understand the nature and reasons for this rounding error.

I need to convert an integer I receive to a float, and correct the rounding errors that result.  What is the best way of doing this?  "Best" in my case means Pythonic and fast.

The integer in question has 6 implied decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store it as a string with 6 decimal places *for display*, then you can use string formatting:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> n = 5352800
>>> d = 1000000
>>> n/d
5.3528
>>> '%.6f' % (n/d)
'5.352800'
```

If you want it stored as a number with 6 decimal places *for further computation* (though this probably isn't what you want), you should use the `decimal` module. Use the formatted string from above and use it as the argument to `decimal.Decimal`.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('%.6f' % (n/d))
Decimal('5.352800')
```

If your goal is further computation, it would probably be more performant to do everything in `decimal` from the beginning rather than messing around with string formatting, i.e.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> n = Decimal(5352800)
>>> d = Decimal(1000000)
>>> n/d
Decimal('5.3528')
```

This prints differently (i.e. with fewer decimal places), but `Decimal('5.352800') == Decimal('5.3528')`, and the two forms should behave identically in all numerical operations. Note also that you don't need the `__future__` import - division on decimals is automatically true division rather than floor division.

Comment: Thanks.  Formatting and then constructing a `Decimal` from that formatted string seems to me like it might be slow.  Is it?

Comment: @JohnDibling I'm honestly not sure; I've never used decimal in anything that needs to be performant. I suspect it would be faster to initialize `n` and `d` as decimals and then go from there, i.e. `n = decimal.Decimal(5352800); d = decimal.Decimal(1000000); n/d`. This gives you six decimal places by construction and saves you the formatting step. The only difference is that the decimal will print as `Decimal('5.3528')` rather than `Decimal('5.352800')`. In all numerical operations, it should behave identically.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm going to use your latest suggestions from the comments.  It seems optimal for my purposes.

Comment: Just to point out that `str(Decimal(5352800)/Decimal(1000000))` yields exactly the right string for display purposes.

Comment: `>>> str(Decimal(5352800)/Decimal(1000000))

'5.3528'`